# Trying to ping a few devices using Batch arrays fails to resolve correctly

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I am trying to make a batch file to quickly ping a number of devices to make sure they are all still on the network. If I type the commands in by hand, it seems give the expected output once, but doesn't seem to loop through the other iterations. Putting them in a batch file and running it somehow messes with my ability to call a variable. The IP just comes up as "i"

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for the help.

```
set Device[0].Name=PC1
Set Device[0].IP=192.168.1.1
set Device[1].Name=PC2
Set Device[1].IP=192.168.1.2
set Device[2].Name=PC3
Set Device[2].IP=192.168.1.3

set _filepath=%userprofile%
echo %date% %time% > %_filepath%

SET /A i=0
:loop

IF %i%==3 GOTO END
call ping -n 1 %IDF[%i%].IP% | find "TTL=" >nul
if errorlevel 1 ( 
    call echo %IDF[%i%].Name% IS OFFLINE >> %_filepath%
) else (
    call echo %IDF[%i%].Name% Online >> %_filepath%
)
SET /A i=%i%+1
GOTO :loop
:END
```

Comment: You need to double the outer percent symbols for the array variables when using CALL.

Comment: Or use delayed expansion and `!IDF[%i%].IP!`, _(taking account that you change `IDF` to `Device` to match the names you've defined earlier, or replacing your six instances of `Device`, with `IDF`)_. Also do not define a variable unnecessarily, there's no need to creat a new veriable name `_filepath`, and give it the content of `%userprofile%`, just use `> "%userprofile%"` instead, but please note that you have not given a file name for your output, you cannot send it to a directory spec.

Comment: I made a few mistakes editing the source code to post it here...yes, variable names match. I'm using a variable for the filepath so that multiple people can use the batch script. The actual filepath being used is %filepath%\thefilepath\output.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In place of `set /a i=0` onwards,

```
for /L %%s in (0,1,2) do (
 CALL ping -n 1 %%Device[%%s].IP%% | find "TTL=" >nul
 if errorlevel 1 ( 
    CALL echo %%Device[%%s].Name%% IS OFFLINE >> %_filepath%
 ) else (
    CALL echo %%Device[%%s].Name%% Online >> %_filepath%
 )
)
```

The `for /L (start,step,end)` command can then be easily altered to process an extended list without using a `goto`

Noting that I severely suspect your setting of `_filepath` since it appears to be assigned a directoryname, not a filename

Also, use `set "var1=data"` for setting values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. In comparisons, use `if "thing1" == "thing2" ...` to avoid problems caused by spaces in `thing1/2`.

Comment: It does go to a file name, I just took out everything personal in it and put generic information. I just forgot to put in a file name for the code above.  
Now if I run it with those changes, I get the following output.  
`C:\Users\admin\Batch Files>(
call ping -n 1 %IDF[43].IP%   | find "TTL="  1>nul
 if errorlevel 1 (call echo %IDF[43].Name% IS OFFLINE  1>>C:\Users\filepath\file.txt )  else (call echo %IDF[43].Name% Online  1>>C:\Users\filepath\file.txt )
)`

Comment: Ignore my last comment. It did run correctly. It just doesn't look like it when reading it in the CMD output. The output in the file was correct. Thanks for the help.